# What is the right place to add a preprocessor in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have added redux to my application. I want to understand what is the right place to add preprocessor, that would processor data returned by asynchronous call made by reducer.

I have a `fetch` function that is generic and returns a resource based on what param is passed to it.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchUsers: filters => dispatch(fetch('USERS')),
  fetchRegions: filters => dispatch(fetch('REGIONS'))
});
```

Now once this call is done, it would update the props that have following binding:

```
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
      users: store.users
      regions: store.regions
});
```

Now before the above mentioned update on props happen, I would like to preprocess the array based on how the component that would use these want the array to be.

Where should I write the preprocessor.

Comment: Reducers are meant to be pure. You might want to look into redux-thunk to handle asynchronous data fetching in your action generators. sagas may be an option as well.

Comment: If you want to preprocess the data and have many other components to use the same pre processed data in same fashion, then you can preprocess the data once  you receive it from the asynchronous call and then dispatch it.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler I am using redux-thunk but the thing is fetch method is common that just returns the resource being requested (In the fetch reducer).

Comment: @Mahima so I am using a reducer to fetch the resource. Are you saying that I put the preprocessor within the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible place would probably be within the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. In here you can check if that data you are expecting to receive has changed, and if so you can do your relevant processing on it and store the result in local state.

Comment: That method is deprecated. And can cause unwanted issues is what I have heard.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. Seems to now be `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`.